# PHP Login system with multiple accounts

Tags: php, authentication, multiple-users

I want to make a basic PHP Login system with multiple accounts. My problem is when you try to login as user1 with the user2's password, the code somewhy lets you. But I don't want to allow you to login with another password. Any idea how to make it?

Code:

```
<?PHP
$local_user1 = "user1"; 
$local_password1 = "123"; 
$local_user2 = "user2"; 
$local_password2 = "456"; 
$local_user3 = "user3"; 
$local_password3 = "789"; 
if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $u_post = $_POST['username'];
    $p_post = $_POST['password'];

    if ($local_user1 == $u_post || $local_user2 == $u_post || $local_user3 == $u_post) 
    {
        if ($local_password1 == $p_post || $local_password2 == $p_post || $local_password3 == $p_post) 
        {
            echo "hello, ".$local_user."!";   
            die();
        }
        echo "Te username or password are not correct !";
        die(); 
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Te username or password are not correct !";
        die(); 
    }
}
?>
<html> 
<body> 
    <form action="" method="POST" >
        <input type="text"  name="username" placeholder="Enter username" /> 
        </br> 
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" />
        </br> 
        <input type="submit" name="login" /> 
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Because you never actually check that if the user is $local_user1 the password must be $local_password1 = "123";

Comment: A database would in fact simplify this process. Actually an array would also

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know it would be better with database, but I don't really want to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple purposes, you need to rearrange your `if` statements

```
if (($user == "user1" && $pass == "pass1") || ($user == "user2" && $pass == "pass2") || ($user == "user3" && $pass == "pass3")) {
    //Login successful
}
```

That way it checks to see if it matches the username and password based on a set of username and passwords and not just checks to see whether A username is correct and A password is correct, however you should redesign your system to use a database because if you are to have multiple users, you cannot simply add one of those if conditions for every user

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in conditions.

```
if ($local_user1 == $u_post || $local_user2 == $u_post || $local_user3 == $u_post)
```

and after that again if with OR.

try with && like in pseudocode

```
$local_user1 == $u_post && $local_password1 == $p_post
```

**OR**

```
$local_user2 == $u_post && $local_password2 == $p_post
```

**OR**

```
$local_user3 == $u_post && $local_password3 == $p_post
```

Comment: It is likely the OP doesn't know how to write this. You should write out a complete answer in PHP using the `()`s as needed.